# Absolute paths module imports don't show in intellisense in mixed JS/TS Project

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm trying to use absolute paths with my tsconfig.json. Right now I can only get absolute paths to work in .ts and .tsx files but not .js and .jsx for some reason.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node16",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/**/*.js",
    "./src/**/*.jsx",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `"allowJs" : true` key value in my tsconfig.json